# Using function(this) onclick, and call the function also when pressing a specific button in Javascript / html

Tags: javascript, html, this

I am struggling with the following issue.
I have a HTML page with a button that changes it's name/value when the button is clicked with the mouse. I would also like this value to change when pressing a key on the keyboard, but I can't manage to fix this.

The code for the button is as follows:

```
<input type ="button" name="pin" value="PIN" id="toggle1" onclick="myFunctionPIN(this)">
```

It calls `myFunctionPIN(this)` function, which looks like this:

```
function myFunctionPIN(obj) {
    if (obj.value == "PIN")
        obj.value = "CASH", myform.pin2.value = "CASH";
    else
        obj.value = "PIN", myform.pin2.value = "PIN";   
}
```

This changes the value of the button to either "CASH" or "PIN". I would now also try to have this change when a person enters the letter 'c' on it's keyboard. To do this, I added an eventListener:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownTextField, false);

function keyDownTextField(c) {
  var keyCode = c.keyCode;
  if(keyCode==67) {
    myFunctionPIN();
  }
}
```

I Have tried to call myFunctionPIN in several ways:
`myFunctionPIN(this)`, `myFunctionPIN(obj)`, `call(myFunctionPin(this))`, but to no avail. Is there a way to have the value of the button change with the press of the 'c' button, or do I need to set it up differently?

Thanks in advance if someone took the time to read and understands the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing through the object as a function parameter, I would recommend removing the function parameter entirely, and instead targeting the desired element with **[`document.getElementById('toggle1')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)**. This way, you don't even have to worry about modifying the event listener; it will already work as expected:

```js
function myFunctionPIN() {
  var target = document.getElementById('toggle1');
  if (target.value == "PIN")
    target.value = "CASH";
  else
    target.value = "PIN";
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownTextField, false);

function keyDownTextField(c) {
  var keyCode = c.keyCode;
  if (keyCode == 67) {
    myFunctionPIN();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="pin" value="PIN" id="toggle1" onclick="myFunctionPIN()">
```

If you do decide to use the function parameters, instead of passing through `this` or `obj`, you need to assign the **target** element in the `keyDownTextField` function. You want to target `#toggle1`, so you need to pass *that* into the call to `myFunctionPIN`:

```js
function myFunctionPIN(obj) {
  if (obj.value == "PIN")
    obj.value = "CASH";
  else
    obj.value = "PIN";
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownTextField, false);

function keyDownTextField(c) {
  var target = document.getElementById('toggle1');
  var keyCode = c.keyCode;
  if (keyCode == 67) {
    myFunctionPIN(target);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="pin" value="PIN" id="toggle1" onclick="myFunctionPIN(this)">
```

Also, be very wary if you're using this script to *actually* exchange money; there's all *sorts* of security implications and compliance you need to consider!

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the DOM element object explicitly (`getElementById` is fine). I also would recommend not to use "onclick" attribute (especially in case you are already using `addEventListener`):

```
<input type ="button" name="pin" value="PIN" id="toggle1">
```

The code:

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('toggle1');

function myFunctionPIN() {
  myElement.value = myElement.value == "PIN" ? "CASH" : "PIN"; 
} 

function keyDownTextField(c) {
  if(c.keyCode == 38) {
    myFunctionPIN();
  }
}  
myElement.addEventListener("click", myFunctionPIN, false);
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownTextField, false);
```